# Build folder not generating in android studio project

Tags: android, build, apk, android-studio-3.0, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Migrated to gradle kotlin dsl and ever since running the project from android studio fails to generate a build folder and an apk. Build succeeds but installation fails with the message:

```
The APK file /Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/project/app/build/outputs/apk/Stage/debug/stage-debug.apk does not exist on disk.
Error while Installing APK
```

This build folder is not being generated at all. Before migrating to gradle kotlin dsl, apk would be picked from build/intermediates/.....splitapk.apk

I am using android studio 3.4 RC3

Answer (score 1):

Project View，Show Options Menu->Show Excluded Files

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Build -> (Build Apk's / Bundle) -> Build Apk on Studio. Then you will see it under app->build->outputs->apk